# Как я могу обратиться к ключу внутри словаря если этот ключ лежит еще и в массиве. Питон

Tags: python, json, dict, pytest

У меня есть JSON который приходит в ответ на неправильный запрос. В этом JSON внутри тела указывается какое конкретное поле было передано не верно. Как мне обратиться к этому ключу что бы проверить его значение?

Вот JSON:

```
{
    "status": 400,
    "description": "BAD_REQUEST",
    "message": "Ошибка валидации",
    "errors": [
        {
            "field": "tag",
            "message": "Не переданы параметры"
        }
    ]
}
```

Мне нужно проверить что field == tag.
Я пробовала обращаться как response_text.get("field"), но получаю None, т.к я ищу ключ который является по сути value для ключа errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
q = '''{
    "status": 400,
    "description": "BAD_REQUEST",
    "message": "Ошибка валидации",
    "errors": [
        {
            "field": "tag",
            "message": "Не переданы параметры"
        }
    ]
}'''

# 1
qq = eval(q)
print(type(qq))
# <class 'dict'>

# 2
import json

qq = json.loads(q)
print(type(qq))
# <class 'dict'>
print(qq['errors'][0]['field'])
# tag

#3
import requests

response = requests.get(url)
print(response.json()['errors'][0]['message'])
```